# Ajax load more post button not showing

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, ajax, javascript, rest-api

I have some alpine.js and ajax that is loading wordpress posts on click of a button, this is working well.

however I am now trying to add some code to the button to hide if no post available to load, im doing this with my button by adding `x-show="total > (limit + offset)"`.
my limit is 6 and offset is null and post count is 10 so it should show the button, however its hidden.

im think the problem could be `getTotal()`is not correctly getting my total setting the button to be hidden.

or my ajax i need to call the total.

Any help with this is much appreciated, once again if I remove `x-show="total > (limit + offset)"` my button shows and loads more post, however dose not hide is no more post available

Bellow is my Alpine.js, AJAX and html/php wordpress code

```
<script>
Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
    posts: "",
    limit: 6,
    total: null,
    category: null,
    post_type_js: post_id,
    showDefault: true,
    showFiltered: false,
    offset: null,
    
    filterPosts(id) {
        this.showDefault = false;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.category = id;
        this.offset = 0; // <-- reset offset to zero
        this.fetchPosts();
    },
    
     loadMore() {
        this.loadingMore = true;
        this.offset += 6;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.fetchPosts(true);
    },

    fetchPosts(append = false) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
        formData.append("limit", this.limit);
        formData.append("post_type_js", this.post_type_js);
        formData.append("offset", this.offset); // <-- Add new data to the form

        if (this.category) {
            formData.append("category", this.category);
        }

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
            if (append) {
                // Appends posts to the end of existing posts data
                this.posts = this.posts.concat(res.posts);
            } else {
                // Resets the posts data with new data
                this.posts = res.posts;
            }

            this.loading = false;
        });
    },
    
    getTotal() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("action", "filterPosts");

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
        this.total = res.total;
    });
},

init() {
    this.getTotal();
}

}));
})
     </script>
```

**html / wordpress php**

```
  <body>
        <div x-data="filterPosts('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>')">
    <section <?php theme_section_attr_id() ?> <?php theme_section_attr_class('main-section js-posts') ?>>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="heading mx-0">
          <?php $before_title = get_sub_field('before_title');
          if ($before_title) : ?>
            <strong class="sub-title"><?php echo $before_title ?></strong>
          <?php endif ?>
          <?php $title = get_sub_field('title');
          if ($title) : ?>
            <h2><?php echo $title ?> </h2>
          <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    
          <div class="head js-posts-search-text">
            <?php if ($search_value) : ?>
              <h2 class="h5 fw-semibold"><?php printf(__('Showing results for “%s”', 'base'), $search_value) ?></h2>
            <?php endif ?>
          </div>
          
    <!--alipne js dynamic post start-->
        <div class="has-filter row flex-md-row-reverse">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 js-posts-holder">
                
            <!-- Posts Column -->
                <div x-show.important="showDefault" class="row cards-area js-posts-items">
                    <!-- Default posts query -->
                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/posts-filter/default-query' ); ?>
                </div>
                    <!-- Filtered posts -->
                <div x-show.important="showFiltered" x-html="posts"class="row cards-area js-posts-items">
                </div>
                <!-- Load More Posts -->
                
           <!-- Load More Posts -->
    <div @click="loadMore()" x-show="total > (limit + offset)"  class="text-center mt-12 pt-5">
        <button class="">
            Load More
        </button>
    </div>
             </div>
                
            <!-- Filtered posts -->
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                 <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/posts-filter/filter-query' ); ?>
            <!-- Filtered end -->
             </div>   
        </div>
        </div>
    <!--alipne js dynamic post end-->
    
    </section>
    </div>
    </body>
```

**Ajax**

```
// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');

function filterPosts()
{
    $response = [
        'posts' => "",
    ];
        // New args for an All Posts Query
    $all_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // returns all posts
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    
    $filter_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    
    if (isset($_POST['offset'])) {                      
    $filter_args['offset'] = max (0, (int)$_POST['offset']);
    }

    if ($_POST['limit']) {
        $filter_args['posts_per_page'] = $_POST['limit'];
    }
    
     if ($_POST['post_type_js']) {
        $filter_args['post_type'] = $_POST['post_type_js'];
    }

    if ($_POST['category']) {
        $filter_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
        
        // Get the total number of posts for the category
        $all_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];

    }

    $filter_query = new WP_Query($filter_args);
    
    // New All Posts Query
    $all_query = new WP_Query($all_args);

    

    if ($filter_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($filter_query->have_posts()) : $filter_query->the_post();
            $response['posts'] .= load_template_part('/template-parts/posts-filter/single-post');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}


function load_template_part($template_name, $part_name = null, $args = [])
{
    ob_start();
    get_template_part($template_name, $part_name, $args);
    $var = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $var;
}
```